# MySQL JOINS without where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

I know that in MySQL SQL it only makes sense to index those fields you use in the WHERE clause. But if you are using JOINS, i believe that the JOIN also acts as the WHERE clause because it is comparing two fields. For example:

```
select b.name, p.location 
from Branch as p, Person as p
where b.id = p.id;
```

is the same as

```
select b.name, p.location
from Branch as p
INNER JOIN Person as p ON (p.id = b.id);
```

So my understanding is that the INNER JOIN = WHERE clause in a way, or translated that way by MySQL, and hence can be indexed on i.e, a columns used on a JOIN are indexed (if they have indexes created on them). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, an `inner join` can equate to a `WHERE clause`, just be careful when using `LEFT/RIGHT` joins as these are not limiting joins.

Comment: @The Georgia Yes you are right. It will similar as INNER Join.

Comment: I would suggest that not only can columns be usefully indexed for a join, they SHOULD be indexed for such a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where and Join are pretty similar. However, Join is more at table level, and where is more at column level. Yes, you are corrrect.

Comment: Are all LEFT JOINS never indexed?

Comment: usually no, otherwise we could use join which is much faster than left join.