# Use an index on a join without "where"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to use an index on a join if there is no limiting where on the first table.

Note: this is not a line-by-line real-case usage, just a thing I draft together for understanding purposes. Don't point out the obvious "what are your trying to obtain with this schema?", "you should use UNSIGNED" or the likes because that's not the question.

Note2: this [MySQL JOINS without where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906085/mysql-joins-without-where-clause) is somehow related but not the same

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
         id_post INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         text VARCHAR(100)
       );

CREATE TABLE related (
         id_relation INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         id_post1 INT NOT NULL,
         id_post2 INT NOT NULL
       );

CREATE INDEX related_join_index ON related(id_post1) using BTREE;
```

Query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM posts FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN(PRIMARY) INNER JOIN related ON id_post=id_post1 LIMIT 0,10;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84597/3

As you can see, the index is being used on the second table, but the engine is doing a full table scan on the first one (the FORCE INDEX is there just to highlight the general question).

I'd like to understand if it's possible to get a "ref" on the left side too.

Thanks!

**Update**: if the first table has significantly more record than the second, the thing swap: the engine uses an index for the first one and a full table scan for the second http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a3bb/1 Still, no way to get indexes used on both.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html

Comment: Also read this answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897763/mysql-explain-showing-all-type-although-index-exists/27899245#27899245

Answer (score 3):

The DBMS has an optimizer to figure out the best plan to execute a query. It's up to the optimizer to decide whether to use an index or simply read the table directly.

An index makes sense when the DBMS expects only few records to read from a table (say 1% of all rows only). But once it expects to read many records (say 99% of all rows) it will not use the index. The threshold may lie at low as 5% (i.e. <= 5% -> index; > 5% table scan).

There are exceptions. One is when an index holds all columns needed. Then the table itself doesn't have to be read at all. Another may be when the optimizer thinks an index access may result faster in spite of having to read many rows. It's also always possible the optimizer simply guesses wrong.

Comment: A wrong guess of the query optimizer has a very low chance to happen for such simple queries. But it is good you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) on the MySQL documentation about this subject.

Regarding the possibility to get a `ref` on the first table from the query, the short answer is `NO`.

The reason is obvious: because there is no `WHERE` clause **ALL** the rows from table `posts` are analyzed because they could be included in the result set. There is no reason to use an index for that, a full table scan is better because it gets all the rows; and because the order doesn't matter, the access is (more or less) sequential. Using an index requires reading more information from the storage (index and data).

MySQL will use the join type `index` if all the columns that appear in the `SELECT` clause are present in an index. In this case MySQL will perform a `full index scan` (join type `index`) instead of a `full table scan` (join type `ALL`) because it requires reading less information from the storage (an index is usually smaller than the entire table data).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a3bb/1 I actually got a eq_on the left table. Still, the answer look solid to me. Will accept it soon if noone provides a different one.

Comment: Not using `WHERE` doesn't mean there will always be a table scan. `WHERE` is not always needed if the `JOIN` conditions are optimal.

Comment: Just a note: you wrote "ALL the rows from table posts are included in the result set". It's an **INNER** JOIN, so rows on the first table won't be included if there isn't a matching one on the second. I think using an index should help here?

Comment: On `INNER JOIN`s MySQL is free to swap the tables if it gets a better execution plan this way. Your "left" table (`posts`) is on the second row on the output of `EXPLAIN` and this means MySQL just swapped the tables for you. For each row from table `related` it searches for one or more rows in table `posts` using the `eq_ref` join type because it can use an index to identify that/those rows.

Comment: @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini you're right, not all the rows will be included in the result set but all of them are read; the final decision about including them or not depends of the content of the joined table and an index on the first table cannot give any hint about that. I modified the answer.

Comment: @EternalHour not using `WHERE` requires the analysis of all the rows from the first table listed in the `EXPLAIN` output. No index on that table could tell if the row will land on the final result set because this depends of the presence of matching rows on the second table. A full index scan will be used instead of a full table scan if the index contains enough information to fulfill the `SELECT` clause, not for filtering but only because it involves reading less information from the storage.